# Silverlight and VS 2005 or VS 2008 Express Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

Is is possible to create silverlight content in C# using Visual Studio 2005 Professional or Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition? I can't find an answer on Microsoft's web site. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if the express edition is [Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/).  Here is a quote from [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/16/update-on-silverlight-2-and-a-glimpse-of-silverlight-3.aspx) from the guy who runs the development team for Silverlight at Microsoft:

> Developers can use either VS 2008 or
>   the free Visual Web Developer 2008
>   Express to open and edit Silverlight 2
>   projects, and get a powerful
>   code-focused .NET development
>   environment.

Comment: "the guy who runs the development team"...nice one - that's the Mighty Scott Guthrie you're talking about :-)

Comment: @Joan Miro: Yes indeed :-) I didn't know quite how to phrase that and eventually went with a quote taken from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/about.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I belive you can with 2008 express.

Make sure you install SP1 to 2008 then install everything else from [here](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/) (it has the SP1 download as well)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at Visual Web Developer Express and the [Silverlight Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C22D6A7B-546F-4407-8EF6-D60C8EE221ED&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

2005 i think you can only create 1.0 project ; and yes you can create SL 2.0 projects in VS 2008 express(visual web developer) but you will need SP1 and the tools everything you need is [here](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/)