# Create ASP.net website with silverlight controls in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2005

I am having only Visual Studio 2005. Is it possible to create asp.net website with silverlight controls in **Visual Studio 2005**.

If yes what are the things I need to install and provide the samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can get the VS2008 Express Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598812/silverlight-and-vs-2005-or-vs-2008-express-edition/599784)

or try to follow [this old blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/06/04/silverlight-with-visual-studio-net-2005.aspx) which refers to SL 1.1 only

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will need Visual Studio 2008 with SP1 to use silvrlight controls